# Loop Infinito Java

Tags: java

Galera como eu faço pra tirar o Loop Infinito dessa classe? Toda vez que é a última informação do banco de dados ele continua mandando email.

```
public class Dia06 {  

public static final long TEMPO = (14 * 1440);
protected static final String Class = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {  
    Connection conexao = new Conexao().getConnection();
    PreparedStatement stmt = conexao.prepareStatement(
            "SELECT P.duplic, "
                    + "       P.dtemissao, "
                    + "       P.dtvenc, "
                    + "       P.valor, "
                    + "       C.cliente, "
                    + "       P.obs2, "
                    + "       c.email, "
                    + "       P.codcli, "
                    + "       C.telent, "
                    + "       Nvl(P.valordesc, 0) VLDESC, "
                    + "       P.codusur, "
                    + "       P.prest, "
                    + "       P.codcob, "
                    + "       C.ieent, "
                    + "       C.bloqueio, "
                    + "       P.duplic "
                    + "       || '-' "
                    + "       || P.prest          AS TITULO, "
                    + "       P.numtransvenda, "
                    + "       P.codfilial "
                    + "FROM   pcprest P, "
                    + "       pcclient C, "
                    + "       pccob B, "
                    + "       pcfilial F "
                    + "WHERE  P.codcob = B.codcob "
                    + "       AND P.codcli = C.codcli "
                    + "       AND P.codfilial = F.codigo "
                    + "       AND  F.CODIGO = 3 "
                    + "       AND p.codcob NOT IN ( 'DEVP', 'DEVT', 'BNF', 'BNFT', "
                    + "                             'BNFR', 'BNTR', 'BNRP', 'CRED', 'DESD' ) "
                    + "       AND P.dtpag IS NULL "
                    + "       AND p.dtvenc = To_date(SYSDATE)-6");

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()){

        final String cliente = rs.getString("cliente");
        final String dtvenc = rs.getString("dtvenc");
        final String valor   = rs.getString("valor");
        //final String EMAIL   = rs.getString("EMAIL");
        //final String duplic   = rs.getString("duplic");

        Timer timer = null;  
        if (timer == null) {  
            timer = new Timer();  
            TimerTask tarefa = new TimerTask() {  
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

                public void run() {   


                    //criar um update depois que enviar o email.
                    try {  

                        MultiPartEmail emai = new MultiPartEmail(); //classe utilizada para permitir anexos no email  
                        emai.setDebug(true);  
                        emai.setHostName("192.168.2.200"); //servidor SMTP. Aqui usamos um do Gmail  
                        emai.setSmtpPort(25);
                        emai.setAuthentication("ttt@teste.com.br", "898999"); // login e senha da conta Gmail  
                        emai.setSSL(false); //Autentica��o de seguran�a SSL setada como True  
                        //emai.addTo(EMAIL);
                        emai.addTo("teste@yahoo.com.br"); //nome do email que vai receber o bkp do banco de dados. Pode ser o seu para teste  
                        emai.setFrom("nfe@tteste.com.br"); //endere�o de email do remetente  
                        emai.setSubject("Cobran�a de D�vida Ativa"); //assunto  
                        emai.setMsg("Prezado( a ) Senhor( a ): " + cliente

                                +"Prezados,\n\n"

                                +"  Conforme descrito no comunicado emitido anteriormente, informamos que, em virtude do n�o pagamento do t�tulo do t�tulo tal,\n "
                                +"  com vencimento para "+dtvenc+", no valor de R$"+valor+", o(s) mesmo(s) ser�(�o) levado(s) a protesto, e os dados de v. senhoria\n "
                                +"  inscritos nos cadastros de restri��o ao cr�dito.\n\n"

                                +" 

                                +"Certos de sua compreens�o, mantemo-nos � disposi��o para a resolu��o desta pend�ncia. \n\n"

                                +"Por tratar-se de aviso autom�tico enviado eletronicamente, para o caso do referido pagamento j� ter sido efetuado, pe�o que entrem \n"
                                +"em contato para normaliza��o da situa��o descrita. \n\n"

                                +"Bras�lia-DF, xx de Xxxxxxxx de 2014. \n\n"

                                +"Atenciosamente, \n\n"); //carta03

                        emai.send(); //envia o email  
                    } catch (EmailException e) { //exception caso aconte�a algum erro ao enviar o email  
                        e.printStackTrace() ;
                        //chamar metodo  
                    } catch (Exception e) {  
                        e.printStackTrace();  
                    }  

                    System.out.println("saida 1");
                }  
            };  

            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tarefa, TEMPO, TEMPO);  
        }  
    }  

}
```

`

Comment: pelo que pude perceber você está usando thread...tente parar usando tarefa.cancel();

Comment: Obrigado Pedro pela resposta mais aonde devo colocar? eu tentei antes mais não consegui, desculpe a ignorância mais eu to novato na area.

Comment: tenta colocar apos o emai.send();

Comment: ta imprimindo "saida 1"?

Comment: Pedro não deu certo fica dando erro.

Comment: sim ta saindo `saida 1`

Comment: blz entao.. quando terminar não chame o método scheduleAtFixedRate, pois vai repetir a execução .

Comment: mais com o método scheduleAtFixedRate ele faz a contagem do tempo para enviar a carta!!! ou to errado?

Comment: depois do  System.out.println("saida 1"); use (timer.cancel(); e timer.purge();) ou System.exit(0); veja esse link... http://www.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/~jacques/cursos/map/html/threads/timer.html

Comment: veja minha resposta pra ver se ajuda você.

Comment: de boas cara^^ to aqui pra ajudar e ser ajudado quando necessário^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode tentar nessa parte do código adicione as seguintes linhas:

```
                    } catch (Exception e) {  
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                }  

                System.out.println("saida 1");
                timer.cancel();
                timer.purge();
            }  
        };  
    timer.schedule(tarefa, TEMPO).
```

Answer (score 1):

O método Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask, long, long) é usado para repetir a tarefa infinitas vezes por um determinado período de tempo, que neste caso é a cada 20 segundos (14 * 1440 = 20160 milisegundos ~ 20 segundos). Acho que você não precisa de Timer nesse caso. Basta enviar um e-mail depois do outro.

Se você está usando Timer para facilitar a criação da thread, considere utilizar o método [Timer.schedule(TimerTask, long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long)).

Por último, um alerta para:

```
Timer timer = null;
if (timer == null) {
    timer = new Timer();
...
}
```

Essa construção é desnecessária, pois timer sempre será nulo no if. Troque por apenas:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
```

Nesse caso, times sempre será não-nulo.